# What does "long long (^blockFun)() = (long long (^)())moreBlockFun" mean and do?

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to learn and use Blocks effectively.

On the web, I have come across this code:

```
long long (^blockFun)() = (long long (^)())moreBlockFun;
```

I think it is trying to create a block that expects a block that returns a long and I think it is doing some casting somewhere too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a block type cast and yes, the syntax isn't great. We assume that `moreBlockFun` is a block that takes no parameters, and returns something with a sensible cast to long long - this type signature is written `long long (^)()`. So we create a new local name for that block called `blockFun`, with the syntax `long long (^blockFun)()`, and perform the cast.

It's a mess mostly inherited from function pointer type notation, which virtually *every* C programmer has to lookup around 482 times before they remember it. You're not alone!

Comment: ah... awesome.  makes sense now.  is there some syntactical sugar one could sprinkle on all this to make it more readable?

Comment: You can (and should) introduce `typedef`s so you can write "FooBlock" or similar to save yourself the main of using the full signature at all points.

Comment: (1) Use typedefs.  It adds sanity to the insane pointer syntax.  (2) When creating the Blocks syntax, I realized that it made understanding function pointers much easier.  Basically, take any block declaration, replace the ^ with * and you have the equivalent function pointer! :)